# Output from elmo pretrained model

Tags: tensorflow, sentiment-analysis, word-embedding, tensorflow-hub, elmo

I am working on sentiment analysis. I am using elmo method to get word embeddings. But i am confused with the output this method is giving. Consider the code given in tensor flow website:

```
 elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
    embeddings = elmo(["the cat is on the mat", "dogs are in the fog"],
    signature="default",as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

The embedding vectors for a particular sentence vary based on the number of strings you give. To explain in detail let

```
 x = "the cat is on the mat"
 y = "dogs are in the fog"
 x1 = elmo([x],signature="default",as_dict=True)["elmo"]
 z1 = elmo([x,y] ,signature="default",as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

So `x1[0]` will not be equal to `z1[0]`. This changes as you change the input list of strings. Why is the output for one sentence depends on the other. I am not training the data. I am only using an existing pretrained model. As this is the case, I am confused how to convert my comments text to embeddings and use for sentiment analysis. Please explain.
**Note** :To get the embedding vectors I use the following code:

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
            # return average of ELMo features
            return sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(x1,1))
```

Comment: Your question gave me a hint to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, x1[0] and z1[0] is the same. However, z1[1] differs from the result of

```
y1 = elmo([y],signature="default",as_dict=True)["elmo"]
return sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(y1,1))
```

because y has fewer tokens than x, and blindly reducing over outputs past-the-end will pick up junk.

I recommend using the "default" output instead of "elmo", which does the intended reduction. Please see the module documentation.

Comment: x1 = array([[ **0.05517201**, -0.02187633, -0.17496817, ..., -0.36848053,0.09267851,  0.23179102]], dtype=float32)  and                                          
 z1 = array([[ **0.05517215**, -0.02187647, -0.17496812, ..., -0.36848068, 0.09267855,  0.23179094],
       [-0.00665377,  0.12139908, -0.1935362 , ..., -0.08462355,0.07242572,  0.19882451]], dtype=float32) .Using ["elmo"], gave me different result(please observe in the last decimals) and this keeps on changing as you increase the list size i.e, we get different vectors for one sentence.

Comment: Also why does z1[1] differ with y1 ? The vector representation should be same for a sentence. The sentences(strings) in z  = [x,y,...] are independent (consider the case of analyzing different tweets ). So irrespective of the size or the strings present in z , that should not affect the elmo vectors ,right ? I tried changing trainable = False also,but did not work

Comment: Re "last decimals": there's a lot of math happening here in single precision. I'm not exactly sure how the different examples in the batch interact with each other, but a match in five significant digits meets my bar of "equal" for deep learning.

Comment: Re "differ with y1": Please see the module documentation for the significance of input lengths, and the recommendation to use output "default". When a recurrent neural network processes a batch of sequences with unequal lengths, it iterates up to the maximum length and leaves it to a postprocessing ("masking") step to delete the past-the-end outputs of shorter sequences.

Comment: Re "last decimals" : Since there is a difference of only one string, the difference in the values is not considerable. But if (say) z = [list of 1000 strings], the values do change from the first decimal point itself. I did lot of checks. I am repeating 'we get different vectors for each sentence ' and why is that ? Are the weights getting trained (but i am not training the model,just extracting vectors from pretrained model ) ?